# using copy from command to load data to postgres from csv

Tags: postgresql, csv

```
create table emp (emp_id integer,
    emp_name varchar(30),
    registered_course varchar(15),
    progress integer);
```

I'm having data in csv as :

```
emp_id, emp_name, registered_course
1,"vignesh","java",10
2,"rakesh","",
```

i.e., In my csv NULL integer column data is represented as unquoted empty string and NULL varchar data is represented as **""**

Now, when I'm trying to upload csv to Postgres using **copy from command** in place of int columns of postgres I can see NULL is inserted but where as for varchar I can see it's blank/zero length string).

so far my command:

```
String copyQuery="COPY "+tableName+"("+columns+") FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER";
    

long rowsInserted;
    
try {

    rowsInserted = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) conPost)

            .copyIn(

                copyQuery,new FileReader(filePath)

                );

}
```

In documentation :- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html
I can see that NULL Specifies the string that represents a null value and by default it is an unquoted empty string in CSV format. So this is why I can see for null integer data which is in csv as unquoted empty string represented as **NULL** after loading.

But, now how can I make NULL varchar data which in csv as **""** to represented as **NULL** at postgres ??? as of now it is representing as empty string (blank/zero length).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks you @a_horse_with_no_name for providing the current documentation and for correcting my question. Current document resolved my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use force_null, documented at the same place you already linked.

```
copy emp from stdin with (format csv, header, force_null (registered_course));
```